# Get a var's value of a predefined class from generic list in C#

Tags: c#, list, api, generics, var

I'm trying to make an "automatic soccer league getter" with XMLSoccer.com. They have .dll file for library and I managed to do it as instructed in the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkXHo5LhKzA

However, the code of the returned container as below

```
    var liveMatches = requester.GetAllLeagues();
```

I tried to getType of         **liveMatches** and i got the type "**System.Collections.Generic.List`1[XMLSoccerCOM.League]**", so looks like it's a generic List like List(T). But I don't have the T class defined in my code as it's returned from XMLsoccer.com and I can't do anything with it.

I use

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = liveMatches;
```

to display liveMatches to the gridview, there're so many columns. i think they're the private var of the T type.

To make sure, I tried

```
    liveMatches.Find(f => f.Name == "Scottish Premier League");
```

to check out what's in the liveMaches. After "f." are those columns title from the datagridview.

Say that I wan't to get just some columns like "Name", "Stadium" and "Homegoal" from just row 2 of the List then how do I do that? I might could have done it by getter() if T type is defined by me. Thank you.

Comment: If you have referenced their DLL then surely that `XMLSoccerCOM.League` is defined in that DLL.  Use the Object Browser window to see what assemblies your project has access to, what namespaces those assemblies contain and what types those namespaces contain.  I think you'll find that type listed there.

Comment: Yup, it's defined in there but there's no method that can read the data, i don't know if is there any way else to read the value...

Comment: Why would you need a method?  It's a property.  You get it's value the same way you do any other property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question should be obvious.  Your `List<XMLSoccerCOM.League>` is just like any other generic `List` and the properties of your `League` objects are just like any other properties.  You're trying to complicate something that is very simple, e.g.

```
var leagues = requester.GetAllLeagues();

foreach (var league in leagues)
{
    MessageBox.Show(league.Name, "Name");
}
```

You get any other property value of the `League` objects the same way.  If you only want the first two leagues in the list then use `leagues.Take(2)`.

Comment: Oops, I've never thought about this. C# is new to me. Thank you, I'll try it out.